# Laptop Rarely Detects Wireless Network Login/Redirect Pages

Tags: network, wifi, airport

I've been having trouble recently connecting to wireless networks with a login page - the kind you see with Gogo Inflight, many hotels, etc. where you connect to a network, launch a browser, and it redirects you to a login page.

Recently, while talking to tech support for one such network (they ended up just giving me access based on my MAC address), they suggested it was because I had fixed DNS servers, particularly `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`.

Does this make any sense and if so, is there another way those should be set up to allow the detection of redirects?

Answer (score 1):

System Prefs > Network... set to automatic, using DHCP. If that's what you already have set, then go to Advanced > DNS, select each custom DNS server & hit the - key.

There is usually little point to using anything other than the DNS servers allocated by your ISP or any hotspot. Custom DNS is usually a short-term fix for local server issues, not a long-term alternative.